# Single version update Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, version

i have to update an angular 7.x project to angular 8.2.0, so i've read online of `ng update`.

I have a global angular version equal to my update target version (8.2.0) but ng update forces me to update to the latest version.

```
Your global Angular CLI version (8.2.0) is greater than your local
version (7.3.5). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
    We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

      Name                                      Version                  Command to update
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/cdk                              7.3.3 -> 13.3.1          ng update @angular/cdk
      @angular/cli                              7.3.5 -> 13.3.0          ng update @angular/cli
      @angular/core                             7.2.8 -> 13.3.0          ng update @angular/core
      @angular/core                             7.2.8 -> 7.2.16          ng update @angular/core
      @angular/fire                             5.1.1 -> 7.3.0           ng update @angular/fire
      @angular/material                         7.3.3 -> 13.3.1          ng update @angular/material
      @nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine            7.1.1 -> 8.2.6           ng update @nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine
      @nguniversal/express-engine               7.1.1 -> 13.1.0          ng update @nguniversal/express-engine
      @ngx-i18nsupport/tooling                  1.1.2 -> 8.0.3           ng update @ngx-i18nsupport/tooling
      ng-mocks                                  7.7.0 -> 13.3.0          ng update ng-mocks


    There might be additional packages that are outdated.
    Run "ng update --all" to try to update all at the same time.
```

Is there a way to do this using `ng update --all` or not? Do I have to use [Angular update guide](https://update.angular.io/)?

I have also tried  `ng update @angular/cli --from="7.3.5" --to="8.2.0"` but it does not work.

````
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr" has an incompatible peer dependency to "ng-packagr" (requires "^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0", would install "13.3.0").
                  Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=2.3.1 <8.0.0 || >7.0.0-beta <8.0.0" (extended), would install "13.3.0").
                  Package "ng-mocks" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires ">=5.x <=7.x" (extended), would install "13.3.0").
                  Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires ">=2.3.1 <8.0.0 || >7.0.0-beta <8.0.0" (extended), would install "13.3.0").
                  Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "7.2.8" (extended), would install "13.3.0").
                  Package "@ismaestro/ngx-example-library" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" (extended), would install "13.3.0").
                  Package "@angular/fire" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" (requires ">=6.0.0 <8" (extended), would install "13.3.0").
                  Package "@nguniversal/express-engine" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-server" (requires "^7.1.4" (extended), would install "13.3.0").
                  Package "tsickle" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires "~3.3.1", would install "4.6.3").
                  Package "@angular/fire" has an incompatible peer dependency to "zone.js" (requires "^0.8.0", would install "0.11.5").
                  Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "^6.0.0", would install "7.5.5").```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because when you do `ng update` you are not defining a specific version.
You should use something like `ng update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10` etc...

Its not recommended to go from Angular 7 to Angular 13 in a single update, instead you should go version by version like:

- Angular 7 -> Angular 8,
- Angular 8 -> Angular 9.1

Follow this Angular Update Guide and you should be fine, at the bottom you have specific instructions you should do before each update
https://update.angular.io/